# Как отправить запрос telegram bot api

Tags: python-3.x, telegram

https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.checkChatInvite подскажите как отправлять запрос данного метода?
я отправлял https://telegram.org/bot/checkChatInvite так и  https://telegram.org/bot/messages.checkChatInvite, они не работают

Comment: А как отправляли? Покажите пример кода

Comment: я пытался requests.get() и в браузере.

Comment: Там все несколько сложнее, да и это не ответ, я ведь просил конкретный код (всякие токены и прочее убрать). Вообще, лучше используйте готовые библиотеки, например: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/f3d01cdc88ebd29b3a7ad23aed36c6acc4ba8351/telegram__telethon__examples/print_dialogs.py#L12

Comment: я видел данную библиотеку, однако выдает такую ошибку:    from telethon.tl.functions.messages.check_chat_invite import CheckChatInviteRequest
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telethon.tl.functions.messages.check_chat_invite'; 'telethon.tl.functions.messages' is not a package

Comment: поиск `CheckChatInviteRequest` в репозитории библиотеки выдал такой пример https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/1d6fd7898adf2b25d697463600183391636aa83d/telethon/client/users.py#L515 теперь останется посмотреть откуда импортировать функцию и все. Если не сможете с этим справиться, то можно задать вопрос в Issues репозитория или тут. А так это `from telethon.tl.functions.messages import CheckChatInviteRequest` (мне стало любопытно)

Comment: спасибо большое) я уже поковырялся и нашел)) надеюсь поможет в решении) сейчас не дома

Comment: @gil9red можно ли как то поддерживать с вами связь?)

Comment: Не думаю, что смогу помочь в ваших вопросах -- по клиенту телеграмму у меня знания ограничены примерами из telethon :)

Comment: @gil9red да я не так давно начал писать) и у меня будет очень много других вопросов)))

Comment: Не люблю, когда мне лично пишут вопросы, которые можно было тут задать :)